# Calling getSystemService(); in a CountDownTimer constructor gives NPE

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, countdowntimer

I have a bound service class `Timer`. In it I want to initiate a new `CountDownTimer` that updates a notification.

If I try to move the declarations for `Intent`, `PendingIntent` and `NotificationManager` outside the `onTick()` method body, an exception will occur. It works fine if they are declared and instantiated within the `onTick()` method.
Can anybody help me understand why this is the case and how I can work around it? Creating those objects during every tick works but seems like a waste of resources.

```
private CountDownTimer newDownTimer() {
    return new CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, countDownInterval) {

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.kush.app.stayput.MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            //Do something in every tick
            if (isPaused || isCanceled) {
                //If user requested to pause or cancel the count down timer
                cancel();
            } else {
                tView.setText("TEXT");
                //Put count down timer remaining time in a variable
                timeRemaining = millisUntilFinished;

                //Update notification
                NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.getContext())
                        .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.notification_title))
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setContentText("TEXT")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name);

                mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
            }
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            //Do something when count down finished
            timer = newUpTimer();
        }
    }.start();
}
```

---

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.example.kush.com.kush.app.stayput, PID: 16993
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.kush.app.stayput.countdown.Timer: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2862)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1427)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSystemService(ContextWrapper.java:627)
       at com.kush.app.stayput.countdown.Timer$1.<init>(Timer.java:156)
       at com.kush.app.stayput.countdown.Timer.newDownTimer(Timer.java:153)
       at com.kush.app.stayput.countdown.Timer.reset(Timer.java:147)
       at com.kush.app.stayput.countdown.Timer.<init>(Timer.java:85)
       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2859)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(ActivityThread.java) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1427) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: This seems like a lifecylce bug.Context is not existing yet. Is it possible that you create the CountDownTimer in an constuctor? Or anywhere else before Activty.onCreate() was called?

Comment: Only one activity exists, MainActivity.class. It exists as it is the same context the service is being launched from. Also there is no code in the return CountDownTimer; call that sets context anyway.

Comment: try using: `this.getSystemService`

Comment: you should call `getSystemService` from `Service#onCreate`, just like [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getSystemService` is a method on the `android.content.Context` class which your activity/service inherits. `CountDownTimer` however does not inherit that class.

You may have to pass a Context to your `newDownTimer` function and ensure you only call it after the Activity/Service  is created.

Comment: Android OS interacts with the service class before calling MainActivity's onCreate(); method. This causes a NPE when trying to do the system call because the context does not exist yet. Since I was calling the method (indirectly) in the constructor of the service, it was affected by this.
I fixed my problem by moving the method from the constructor into the onStartCommand() method of the service class.